# Dragging two Google Maps simultaneously

Tags: maps, draggable, simultaneous

on a web page I want to show 2 maps canvas, one showing satellite view and the other showing map view but if I drag any of those canvas it will also move the other one in the same direction.

I tried Google but couldn't find any relevant info.

Comment: Have you considered using the Hybrid view?

Comment: Hi Ben, no I haven't cause it's more for design purpose than for functionality. Here is a screenshot, might help you understand this. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/268/ltl5contactus.jpg/

Comment: I would like to do this too. My purpose is to show two vector datasets side-by-side for visual comparison. Currently the left-hand map controls are active, and the right-hand map is adjusted to have the same center and zoom as the left-hand whenever these change. But it would be nice to be able to drag/zoom either map.

Comment: @GregBall I found an easier to use map api, you might want to take a look at [leaflet-js](http://leafletjs.com/)